# Negative integrals question

Tags: calculus

What happens when you take the integral of an equation, such as 2x, from 2 to 0 instead of from 0 to 2. Would it be negative since x^2|0 - x^2|2=-4?

Comment: Yes, $\int_2^0 x^2$ is negative. More generally, provided it makes sense, $$\int_a^b f(x) dx + \int_b^a f(x) dx = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this follows from the fact that that $\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c$, by taking $c=a$ and noting that $\int_a^a =0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No problem.

$$\int_{2}^{0}2xdx=x^2\bigg|_{2}^{0}=0^2-2^2=-4.$$